# React native typescript giving me an TS error when using "className"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, tailwind-css

used React for a while now but new to React Native.

I am using tailwind with https://tailwindcss-react-native.vercel.app/installation

```
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

export default function Navigation() {
  return (
    <View className="grid h-screen w-screen place-items-center">
      <Text className="text-red-800">Test</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Tailwind works, the text is red, however I get TS errors under the classnames above ^^

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: ViewProps | Readonly<ViewProps>): View', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<View> & Readonly<ViewProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
      Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<View> & Readonly<ViewProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: ViewProps, context: any): View', gave the following error.
    Type '{ children: Element; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<View> & Readonly<ViewProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Text> & Readonly<TextProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2769)
```

I've followed the expo typescript setup, my tsconfig looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {},
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base"
}
```

Comment: Try some docs to see what props you can provide 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#props, https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#props

Answer (score 18):

Create a file "global.d.ts" in the root level of the app and paste this line

```
/// <reference types="nativewind/types" />
```

After including this file, the TypeScript errors will disappear, and the "className" attribute works perfectly fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this work for me better than the doc itself

Comment: My `app.d.ts` file with the triple-slash directive randomly stopped preventing typescript errors for the `className` prop, changing it to `global.d.ts` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 15):

I have experienced the same issue, and the simplest fix to include the types is to create a new `app.d.ts` file and add a triple-slash directive referencing the types like this:

```
/// <reference types="nativewind/types" />
```

If this does not fix your problem, to get rid of red lines, you can add
`@ts-nocheck` on the top of the file. (Disclaimer, this solution does not solve the problem, just get rids of the warnings, by disabling TS check for specific file)

Comment: Good answer but please remove the recommendation to add @ts-nocheck. If someone is using nativewind with typescript they want typechecking!

Answer (score 9):

By default, the tailwindcss-react-native quick start setup does not include support for TypeScript. However, the [docs](https://tailwindcss-react-native.vercel.app/compilation/babel#typescript) mention how to add it:

Create a file (eg. src/tailwindcss-react-native.d.ts) and paste this line

```
import "tailwindcss-react-native/types.d";
```

After including this file, the TypeScript errors will disappear.

Comment: do i have to npm install tailwindcss-react-native/types.d

Comment: no, only npm install tailwindcss

Answer (score 0):

Nativewind extends the typings provided by react native and then expects you to merge them, they provide the support to write className prop in the following components [image]

to achieve this support I assume you have a src/{rest of your code} type structure, so follow the steps below

1. create an app.d.ts file in the src directory
2. add `/// <reference types="nativewind/types" />` to it

and that's it, you have created a declaration file for your project that references the types provided by the nativewind, and by doing so you have merged their extension of the types to your current existing typings thereby allowing you to use className

Answer (score 0):

If you have followed every installation step and its giving you this error that means you need to clear you cache and re-run your application,

1. stop metro bundler
2. then run `npx expo start --clear`

I think this will clear your problem

Answer (score -2):

React Native `View` and `Text` components don't accept `className` prop, `style` only.

Check the reference: https://reactnative.dev/docs/text

Comment: Ah I see, I was following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=taPz40VmyzQ&t=1011s (29:16). 

It does work and he in the video uses it also, perhaps this is something that tailwindcss-react-native changes but Typescript isn't recognising?

Comment: Yes, take a look https://tailwindcss-react-native.vercel.app/compilation/babel

Comment: Yes that was it, it was this section here: https://tailwindcss-react-native.vercel.app/compilation/babel#typescript

Feel free to add this to your answer and i'll accept it

Comment: how can i solve it because this page : https://www.nativewind.dev/compilation/babel#typescript no longer exist